# Google app engine java filtering date query with day

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am looking for some thing like this.

```
public class User 
{
   private Date createdOn;
}
```

Now i need a query to fetch users created on day 10th of any month or year. 
Like i need users created on 10th Jan 2012, 10th Feb 2012, 10th June 2010.....
How can i get part of a date in gae query?

Thanks,

Ramesh.V

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a date object for whatever date you're looking for and use it as part of the query. There's nothing special about Dates in queries.

Not sure if you're using JDO, JPA or the datastore directly, but either way

See the GQL reference (not really python specific): http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html

SELECT * FROM User WHERE createdOn ==  :date

In JDO it would look something like:

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(User.class);
query.setFilter("createdOn == dateParam");
List<User> results = (List<User>) query.execute(date);
```

Comment: I need to query on day of a date and not on complete date, any ideas?

Comment: Just store the day in the table when you create the row along with the date. Don't be afraid of storing extra data like that in appengine, it's insignificant and definitely the "right" way to do it.

Comment: You can think of @Rick Mangi's suggestion as creating an index for your query. It's extra information "formatted" in the way you need it to make a fast query later.

Comment: Yes, or "partial decomposition" of the data. Very common in no-sql scenarios. It's a lot cheaper to pre-format data you're going to need later and stick it in your database than it is to try to query on it in real time.

Answer (score 1):

For your filter, you could use:

"(createdOn >= p1) && (createdOn <= p2)"

where you have set the parameters p1 and p2 to be the start and finish `Date`s of the day in question.